# How can i show more time a spinner? in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular-material

This is basic the code I'm using https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ajewqc for my spinner.The spinner its showed when the app do the http-request but i want to display the spinner a little bit longer, how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `delay` operator:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .delay(2000)
      .subscribe(res => this.users = res);
}
```

This operator will delay the emission of items from observable after response received.

Comment: Yours is the best answer :)

Comment: Excellent, can you help with other thing about spinner? in other question i have

Comment: Excellent, can you help with other thing about spinner?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant way, anyway you could put another setTimeout on subscription response:

```
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => setTimeout(() => {
          this.users = res
        }, 3000)
        )
    }, 1000);
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-router-basic-example-ljsg5t

Answer (score 0):

(I guess OP just wants to watch spinner a bit longer, say 5 seconds)
Just add more milliseconds (5000) to timeout in `home.component.ts`:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => this.users = res)
    }, 5000);
}
```